# Issue with eclipse code formatter when there are compile errors

Tags: eclipse, formatter

Something, that annoys me for quite a long time is, that the eclipse formatter is removing whitespace between a method with a compile error and the next method.

Since I am using autoformatting as save action this happens quite often. I wonder if there is any possiblity to deactivate the white space removal. Has anyone solved this yet?

Here some pictures to illustrate the behaviour:

Before Saving ->

[image]

After Saving ->

[image]

The blank line between method1() and method2() gets removed by autoformatting. Anyone knows which formatter setting is responsible for this?

Comment: Since Juno I have a similiar problem. But (I guess because of other format settings) complete text blocks are removed! Additionally I have configured formatting as save action which means that most of the time when I save a  not correct file I'll lose some code which I can get only back with Ctrl+Z :( If I remember correctly formatting was disabled as long as code is not error-free in previous eclipse versions.